# Rails coflict ajax and URI.encode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, request

I have a search string that, through my controller, connects to my written library, and sends a get request to a third-party api. The form:

```
<%= form_with(:url => url_for(:controller => 'orders', :action => 'find_drug'), method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :drug_name, nil, class: "search_drug", placeholder:"Find drug..." %>
    <%= button_to "Find", nil, class: "search_drug_button" %>
<% end %>
```

Ajax:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.search_drug_button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'orders/find_drug',
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

controller OrdersController:

```
def find_drug
        response = ApiParser::Parser.new
        drugs = response.get_drug(params[:drug_name]).response

        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: drugs.body}
        end
    end
```

Method in my library (written using the HTTParty gem):

```
module ApiParser
    class Parser
        include HTTParty
        ...
        def get_drug(drug)
            options = "?search.drugs={\"ls\": \"#{URI.encode(drug)}\"}"                                 
            self.class.get(options, format: :json)
        end
        ...    
    end
end
```

In the console, 2 requests are sent (one of the form, directly to the controller with code 200, the second via ajax) and ajax gives me an error 500

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#find_drug

undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #305):

#303         unsafe = Regexp.new("[#{Regexp.quote(unsafe)}]", false)
#304       end
*305       str.gsub(unsafe) do
#306         us = $&
#307         tmp = ''
#308         us.each_byte do |uc|

Extracted source (around line #104):

#102     def escape(*arg)
#103       warn "#{caller(1)[0]}: warning: URI.escape is obsolete" if $VERBOSE
*104       DEFAULT_PARSER.escape(*arg)
#105     end
#106     alias encode escape
#107     #

Extracted source (around line #38):
                                             **#this is my code**
*38             options = "?search.drugs={\"ls\": \"#{URI.encode(drug)}\"}"                                 
#39             self.class.get(options, format: :json)
```

request in console Chrome 200:

```
...localhost:3000/orders/find_drug?utf8=%E2%9C%93&drug_name=%D1%8F%D1%80%&authenticity_token=Ndao2...
```

500:

```
...localhost:3000/orders/find_drug
```

If, in the controller, instead of **params[:drug_name]**, I simply pass the string I want to find, both queries with code 200 work. Having written the whole question, I thought that my ajax is not receiving this particular **params[:drug_name]** , and can not search for an empty value(but it is not exactly). Just starting to work with javascript

I tried to perform such an Ajax request:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.search_drug_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'orders/find_drug',
      data: new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0])
    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

but I got an error

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.param (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (Аптечная_сеть:551)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using form and ajax together?

Comment: just make sure the query is working

Comment: do you want this functionality on ajax?

Comment: yes, to add the result to html

Comment: how to send an Ajax request using my library, so that it would not generate an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me tell you why your code isn't working.

- You're using form and jQuery together
- If you want to use jQuery you should block all the default actions which is happening on your submit button by using `event.preventDefault();` otherwise you'll be sending two requests one with default form submission and other with jQuery.

Solution:

you can use rails default functionality by using `js.erb`.

To get this working.

Use this in your controller code.

```
def find_drug
  response = ApiParser::Parser.new
  @drugs = response.get_drug(params[:drug_name]).response
end
```

- comment out all your `ajax` code.
- replace your code with `form_with(url: '/orders/find_drug', method: :get)`
- create a file in orders folder as `find_drug.js.erb`
- write `console.log('<%= @data %>');` in `find_drug.js.erb`

now check it. If you're still facing problems do let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! write console.log('<%= **@data** %>'); need to replace **@drugs**